# Scrolling background effect on cards

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this nice scrolling background effect on the homepage cards you see in this post https://www.instagram.com/p/CNxCwQIHtgA/

The scrolling is nice and slow unlike what I currently have. I'd like to replicate these cards as closely as possible

```css
.home-category-image-container {
    margin: 1rem;
    height: 18rem;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s ease-in;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 19%), 0 6px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 23%);
}
```

```html
<section class="home-categories">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-md-6 p-2">
          <div class="home-category-image-container" style="background-image: url(https://www.arabianbusiness.com/public/images/2019/05/29/Ferrari_SF90_Stradale_5.jpg)">
          </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-6 p-2">
          <div class="home-category-image-container" style="background-image: url(https://www.arabianbusiness.com/public/images/2019/05/29/Ferrari_SF90_Stradale_5.jpg)">
          </div>
      </div>
         
      <div class="col-md-6 p-2">
          <div class="home-category-image-container" style="background-image: url(https://www.arabianbusiness.com/public/images/2019/05/29/Ferrari_SF90_Stradale_5.jpg)">
          </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Nicescroll plugin! https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();

  }

);
```

Comment: Wow this is something I wish i knew about sooner! Thank you so much!!